# Where are the achievements in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: achievements, mass-effect-3

I'm pretty new with Origin so forgive me if this is obvious. I'm playing Mass Effect 3 and I'm trying to see what the achievements are. Problem is: I can't find an "Achievements" menu item in-game, and I can't find it in the Origin overlay either.

Is there a way to check the achievements without leaving the game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "in-game". You cannot get to them while actively playing as your character, but you can get to them from the main menu when you start the game. They're under **Extras->Accomplishments**.

[image]

Comment: By the way, is there an achievement for completing the game in hardcore? I'd check it myself, but I'm afraid of getting spoilers from the achievements. =)

Comment: @BruceConnor I see one for Insanity, but not for Hardcore.

Comment: @BruceConnor ME series has generally been pretty good about spoiler-free achievements.

Comment: Yeah, most of them were pretty vague, though there was a little bit you could glean from the list.

Comment: @RavenDreamer I'm usually not too worried about this stuff, but with this game in particular I got spoiled even before release just by clicking the Add-Ons page in origin. =/